# Use variable as collation (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have a variable I need to use as a collation;

```
DECLARE @collat sysname;

SELECT @collat = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';

MERGE ...
USING ...
ON (x = y COLLATE @collat)
```

The collation SELECT is actually some magic source which determines which collation to use.

SQL Server seems to not like this throwing

> Incorrect syntax near '@collat'.

Does anyone have any knowledge on using variables for collate?

Thanks

Comment: USE SET instead of SELECT  SO SET @collat =

Comment: [`collation_name must be a literal value.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) you need to use dynamic SQL. But why are you using SQL2008 it's end of life'd

Comment: Thanks mate. You'll have to ask my boss for the reason why we're still using 2008...